# Yet Another Problem Generating Signed Download URL for Google Cloud Storage (in Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

After much research and experimentation, I simply cannot get a Google Cloud Storage signed URL to download something simple. I must be missing something basic. Here's the core code in Python:

```
from google.cloud import storage
def file_get_url(bucket_name, blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(version="v4", expiration=datetime.timedelta(hours=5), method="GET")
    return url
```

Calling `file_get_url('test-bucketrqu', 'vzu8kd2')`, where blob 'vzu8kd2' contains the string `hello`, returns `https://storage.googleapis.com/test-bucketrqu/vzu8kd2?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=%2F20220925%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220925T222429Z&X-Goog-Expires=18000&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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`

Pasting that URL into my browser bar returns

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>GOOG4-RSA-SHA256 20220925T222429Z 20220925/auto/storage/goog4_request 829ae54cd525fc4940f686e6bee4170599644aa7238e90f4085ba4e56dc0a98b</StringToSign>
<CanonicalRequest>GET /test-bucketrqu/vzu8kd2 X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=%2F20220925%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220925T222429Z&X-Goog-Expires=18000&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host host:storage.googleapis.com host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
</Error>
```

Not sure if it matters, but I am running this on a local dev machine using a  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, with the user credentials of an account that has the `Owner` role.  In response to the comments, I have added `Storage Admin` and `Service Account Token Creator` to the role, and in desperation after waiting a few minutes, revoked and redid `gcloud auth application-default login`, to no avail.

Comment: Double-check the time zone, date, and time of your local dev machine.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Good idea, but my local dev machine time is synced to the cloud and appears correct, including time zone.  I can generate a signed URL via the cloud, using the default app engine service account, but not locally via my login credentials.  Locally I can create and read buckets/objects, but the signed URLs do not work as described.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have the IAM role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`? Edit your question and list the roles the problem identity has.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Really appreciate the help.  I have edited the question as requested, and no, the identity used for local dev does not have `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`.  It does have the Owner role, though.  Do I need to explicitly give it a Storage Admin role?  Or somehow just add the permission you mentioned?  It does have many storage permissions, already, and can create buckets and object.

Comment: You can list the IAM permissions of Owner: `gcloud iam roles describe roles/owner`. Then list the roles for `serviceAccountTokenCreator`: `gcloud iam roles describe roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`. When you compare the lists, you will find that the role Owner does not have all the permissions available even for service accounts.

Comment: One last thing to check is how you have access control configured on the bucket. Are you using ACLs or IAM? ACLs are legacy.

Comment: @JohnHanley The bucket uses uniform access control.  I added the Storage Admin and Service Account Token Creator roles to the login, to no avail.  If it matters, the bucket permissions show the service account (which can sign urls on the server) as having Storage Admin access, as does my specific login, but owner accounts have Storage Legacy Bucket Owner (and Object) roles. Not sure if that's a clue of some sort.  Finally, I note that the error message says `Check your Google secret key and signing method`, but I'm not doing anything with a secret key.

Comment: Hi @Dev93, could you please check if your Cloud Storage Bucket is using a domain bucket bound host name?

Comment: @SarahRemo The name of the bucket is `test-bucketrqu`, so I think that means the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Dev93  I've managed to replicate your issue and found out that I'm passing a wrong private key. Can you check if you are using the right private key?

Comment: @SarahRemo - I'm following the directions on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-dev to run `gcloud auth application-default login`, which asks me to login, and it seems to work, because I can then create and read buckets and objects.  I can also sign URLS: I just can't use them :-(

Answer (score 0):

Signed URls are for service accounts, not user accounts.  To generate a signed URL from your local dev environtment with

1. [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
2. [Log in as that service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) and leave `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` unset or download the JSON key file and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to it.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I still can't get the local dev server to generate signed URLs that work (everything works fine when running in production).  I believe I followed your instructions, giving the new service account App Engine and Storage Admin roles, as well as serviceAccountTokenCreator.  You say to log in as that service account,  which I believe meant to use `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.  Correct?  I'm confused because your point 2 seems to imply I don't need to download the JSON key, but that command requires it.